# Accessing Image Path

Tags: iphone

I want to get the Path a image of the photo albums from the iPhone device. and also i need the extension of that image with their name.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've not tried this, but take a look at [UIImagePickerControllerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/prerelease/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html) and the `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` method. I thought the actual path to the image was hidden, but the `info` Dictionary has a key called `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL` which looks like it might be a NSURL to the original image.

```
UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL
The Assets Library URL for the original version of the picked item.
After the user edits a picked item—such as by cropping an image or trimming a movie—the URL continues to point to the original version of the picked item.
The value for this key is an NSURL object.
Available in iOS 4.1 and later.
Declared in UIImagePickerController.h

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

Comment: Can you give me some more detail to find out the path of image.

Comment: Why don't you read the documentation I linked to and look at the sample projects which you can also find in the documentation I linked to...

Comment: newFilePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent: textFieldNormalFile_name.text];
 //newFilePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"ChosenPic.jpg"];
 imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 1.0);
 if (imageData != nil) {
  NSLog(@"HERE [%@]", newFilePath);
  [imageData writeToFile:newFilePath atomically:YES];
 }
 image.image =[UIImage imageNamed:newFilePath];
 NSLog(@"newFilePath:%@",newFilePath);
 path.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:newFilePath];
 NSLog(@"path.text :%@",path.text);