# Retrieve the url of an image taken on the fly and saved in the gallery, how?

Tags: iphone, url, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller, filepath

I allow the user to choose an image from the gallery or take a photo with the camera.
I would to save the image path in both cases so that I can use it to display the image in a second moment.

When the user select an image from the gallery, I can use

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {


    if([[info valueForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerMediaType"] isEqualToString:@"public.image"]) {
           NSURL *imageUrl = [info valueForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"];

}
```

}

Instead, if the user takes a photo on the fly, I save it in the photo roll with:

```
  UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

  UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
```

After saving it, I would to retrieve the corresponding NSURL as the user had selected it.

How could I do?

**EDIT**

My problem isn't about the image chosen from the gallery. I succeed in retrieving the url using the UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL path. My problem is when the user takes a photo with the camera. I can write it in the photo roll, but I should find a way to automatically select it such that

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

is called again and I can use the UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL key to retrieve the corresponding url.

Comment: I hope this would be help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922520/path-and-extension-of-image

Comment: My problem isn't about the image chosen from the gallery. I succeed in retrieving the url using the UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL path. My problem is when the user takes a photo with the camera. I can write it in the photo roll, but I should find a way to automatically select it such that - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info is called again and I can use the UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL key to retrieve the corresponding url.

Comment: do you mean automatically selecting the previous image that was taken and saved

Comment: @7KV7: Yes. By my app, the user takes the photo. When the user clicks on the "use" button I save it in the photo roll. Then I would to retrieve the corresponding url as the user had selected it from the gallery.

Comment: The question with the answer is here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457904/iphone-how-do-i-get-the-file-path-of-an-image-saved-with-uiimagewritetosavedphot
 :)

Comment: @Lachezar Todorov: I had to maintain the compatibility with 3.1 iOS, anyway, I'll consider it for the future. Thank you very much.